# jQuery hide div clicking outside div excluding its child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one div(`sel_optn1`) and i am showing `sel_optn1` on click of li(`opt1`) 
and hiding `sel_optn1` out side click of `sel_optn1`.
It is working fine but if i click on children of `sel_optn1` it is hiding.

I want to hide `sel_optn1` only on out side click, but to exclude `sel_optn1` children's click from hiding `sel_optn1`

see this example which i am trying http://jsbin.com/ahuyak/1/edit

Can any one help me achieving this.

Comment: see this: http://help.dottoro.com/ljgfjsxd.php

Comment: See this: http://jsbin.com/ahuyak/7/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your check function to check clicks on its child elements as well:

```
if(e.target.className !== "sel_optn1" && !$(e.target).parents('.sel_optn1').length)
```

Comment: what if i have n number of children?

Comment: Then you'd need to check if the click was on an element which has the sel_optn1 parent/ancestor: `if(e.target.className !== "sel_optn1" && !$(e.target).parents('.sel_optn1').length)`

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the click target was in the element

```
if(e.target.className !== "sel_optn1" && !$.contains($(".sel_optn1")[0], e.target))
{
    $('.sel_optn1').css({"display":'none'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div(sel_optn1).children().click(function(){stopPropagation ( );})
```

Comment: how to handle i if have events on children? too.

Comment: this is for the childrens of the sel_optn1 but this doesn't mean you cant have events on the childrens individually.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://jsbin.com/ahuyak/11/edit

You have to check all the child elements

Answer (score 0):

You can try `blur` instead: http://jsbin.com/ahuyak/12/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#opt1").click(function(e){
     $('.sel_optn1 , :text').show();
     e.stopPropagation();
   });

   $('.sel_optn1 > :text').blur(function(e){
      $('.sel_optn1 , :text').hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I bound the click event on the document and check if the target that was clicked on is the `.sel_optn1` and then i bound the click event on the document and check its target if its `.sel_optn1` or any of its children, dont hide it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var option = $(".sel_optn1");

  $("#opt1").click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    option.toggle();
  });

  $(document).click(function(e){
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(!(target.is(option) || option.find(target).length)){
      option.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

and a demo: 
http://jsbin.com/ahuyak/15/